# How to check if document exist on SET and WHERE

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to update PITA denormalised db structure.
I know there are already answers on how to check if document exist on get even documentation is pretty clear about it but I just cannot find anything what would check if document exist on update "set" and "where".

**First** I want to check one document if exist before updating

```
 const staffRef = db.collection("staff").doc(uid)

    return staffRef.set({
        employeeProfile: employeeProfile
    }, {
            merge: true
        })...
```

Is there any way to check if that document exist on set or should I first read it to find out if that document exist like this

```
    const staffRef = db.collection("staff").doc(uid)
    return staffRef.get()
        .then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                return staffRef.set({
                    employeeProfile: employeeProfile
                }, {...
```

**Second** I want to check multiple documents on where

```
const staffRef = db.collection("staff").where("employerId", "==", uid)
    const batch = db.batch()

    return staffRef.get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                batch.update(doc.ref, { employerProfile: employerProfile })
            })...
```

Should I read the each doc after forEach if exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** answer: Yes, for a single document, you have to first use the `get()` method to find out if that document exists.

> For a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) that points to a non-existing document,
>   any data access will return 'undefined'. You can use the `exists`
>   property to explicitly verify a document's existence.

**Second** answer: No, in case of the results of a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query), you don't need to check each document: each `doc` you get by looping with `querySnapshot.forEach()` does exist.

> A [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html) contains zero or more `DocumentSnapshot`
>   objects representing the results of a query.

Comment: Hi Renaud. Second: what if there are no documents match that search? How to prevent error it out?

Comment: @ptr.chov Just use the `empty()` method of the `QuerySnapshot`, see  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#empty

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I needed to know

Comment: @ptr.chov PS: just to be sure, note that with `set()` you actually don't need to have the document existing (unless, of course, this is needed for your own functional requirements), while with `update()` you do need it.

Comment: Hi Renaud. Hmm... this is in onUpdate trigger function and set() is giving me an error in loggs when document not exist. I haven’t tried update() method yet because I didn’t even know it exist:). Can you post a link to update method just in case I would not find it?

Comment: Here are the two docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update. You may share (add to your question) your entire Cloud Function code as well as the error message from the log.

Comment: just noticed that the error is only because the profileImg didn't exist... I just read about the update() method and I'm going to change it otherwise it just create a document which I don't want. I don't understand how could I miss that